# What is the adjective of "complex"?

Tags: adjectives

What is the adjective of the word "complex" in this context:

> The echo that is produced by species x in closed habitat is more complex than in open habitat.

Comment: "Complex" is an adjective.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/complex_1?q=complex

Comment: I think what you mean is 'What does *complex* modify?'. If that is the case, I suggest you edit your question to ask that.

Comment: You need to either say "a closed habitat" or "closed habitats"... same with the open ones.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective is describing the echo. Specifically, "the echo that is produced by species x in closed habitat".

I think the word "closed" should probably be replaced by "enclosed", but that may not be necessary. To make it a bit simpler, the sentence could be rephrased as:

> Species x produces a more complex echo in an enclosed habitat than an open habitat.

With complicated sentences like this, I sometimes find it easier to break the sentence up into phrases like this, even as a native speaker.

Comment: Please comment if you need any additional information.